# Different behavior for if-else and ternary operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, copy-constructor, ternary-operator

I have below class in VS2010-SP1, Ternary operator and if-else seems to be working differently for below code on getname method

```
template <int size=120> class StringBuf{
    public:
        StringBuf(const char* src){
            strcpy(s,src);
        }
        // Copy from another StringBuf
        StringBuf(const StringBuf& src){
            strcpy(s,src.get());
        }
        // String access
        operator const char*() const    {return get();}
        const char* get() const { return s ; }
    private:
        char    s[size];
    };

class MyPony{
    StringBuf<10> name;
    public:
        MyPony(char* name_) : name(name_){}
        const char* getname(bool bVal){
            //if( bVal )
            //  return name;
            //else
            //  return "Jimmy";
            return  (bVal==true) ? name : "Jimmy";
        }
};

int main(){
    MyPony pony("Pani");
    const char* getname = pony.getname(true);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use ternary operator getname() method makes a copy of name by calling copy constructor and then calls operator const char* on the temp copy.

If I change ternary operator into if-else the code just calls operator const char* without making a temp copy.

My understanding is that if else and ternary operator should behave the same, but why is this different behavior for this class? Is there something that I'm overlooking?

For ternary operator VS2005 seems to call operator const char* directly .

Comment: Did you try this on a release build, or debug build?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Debug.

Comment: Please try this in release mode.  A compiler is free to optimize away copy construction.

Comment: The common type of `char const [5]` and `StringBuf<10>` is `StringBuf<10>`. Don't use a conditional expression when you don't actually want one. I'm assuming that VS2005 either had a bug in how it determined common types, or you were omitting a `const` somewhere and depended on some Microsoftianism.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Update: tested in release same behavior. Temp object created for ternary and not created for if-else.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I don't clearly understand, the example that I added is stripped down version of a big file where conditional expression is meaningful. The code that I have pasted is all and const is not omitted.

Comment: @Coder777: The fact that your `MyPony` constructor silently accepts a string literal for mutable char pointer and nobody seems to mind leads me to believe that the codebase may hold other "surprises".

Comment: @KerrekSB, MyPony is a fictional class that I created to demonstrate the problem and yes I have missed a const and I should have passed const char* to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Of course: The type of the conditional expression `a ? b : c` is the common type of `b` and `c`, which in your case is `StringBuf<10>`. So either operand must first get converted to that type before the resulting value can be considered for `return`.

There conditional expression is an *expression*, and the `if` statement is a *statement*. They're different things for different purposes. Use the `if` statement in your situation.

---

You might wonder why the common type is `StringBuf<10>` and not `char const *`. That's because of C++11 5.16/3 ("Conditional operator"), which says that implicit conversions are considered. In your case, there is an implicit conversion from `char const [6]` (the type of `"Jimmy"`) to `StringBuf<10>`, but not the other way round, so the common type is uniquely defined. For comparison, if you tried `x ? name : static_cast<char const *>("Jimmy")`, that would not compile.

Comment: 'name' should be returned in the sample code I posted and it is already of type StringBuf<10> then why make a copy of it and call its operator char*?

Comment: x ? name : static_cast<char const *>("Jimmy") compiles.